# Java : methods with generic return types

Tags: java, c#, generics

I have been using a .NET (C#), I am now starting with JAVA. I need a little help on the Generic types in java.

I want a Java equivalent of the below mentioned C# code.

Program.cs

```
    namespace TemplateTest
    {
        class Program
        {

            static object CreateCheeseCake()
            {
                return new { Fruit = "Strawberry", Topping = "Chocolate"};
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                object weaklyTyped = CreateCheeseCake();


                var stronglyTyped = new GrottyHacks().Cast(weaklyTyped,
                                                     new {Fruit = "", Topping = ""});

                Console.WriteLine("CheeseCake : {0} {1} "
                         , stronglyTyped.Fruit, stronglyTyped.Topping);

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

GrottyHacks.cs

```
public class GrottyHacks
    {
        public T Cast<T> (object target, T example)
        {
            return (T) target;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your return you declare some form of object, you need to declare that in Java so add a new class which is the return types ie Class ReturnType { public Fruit; public Topping; },   The reason is you cannot weakly type in Java the way you can in C# and casting is done using the Casting brackets, String out = (String) 12345;

Comment: CreateCheeseCake() method should have obejct's name as return type and return statement should include name of object with its constructor parameters

Comment: @TheresaForster `String out = (String)12345;` is not legal Java.

Comment: If you really want a structure where you can put in any field you want and give each field any value you want, you could use `Map<String,Object>`.  I'm not familiar with this feature of C#, but I'm guessing that it's implemented using a map anyway.

Comment: @ajb, even with autoboxing and autoconversion? I guess you can't cast but you can do System.out.println(1234); and it will work.... Its all about the way he is creating a class with just the variables, that will not work in Java even with generics as Java is more strongly typed than C# in this aspect

Comment: @TheresaForster "autoconversion"???  Not in Java.  Autoboxing only goes from `int` to `Integer` and back, not to `String`.  `println` can take any object because its parameter is declared to be an `Object`.

Comment: @ajb I stand corrected. its 6am and I just woke up...